# WordPress Recommendations

Tags: database, wordpress, plugins, registration, user-registration

I'm pretty adept to Wordpress and handling databases via PHP, but I'm struggling to think of a solution for a client.

The client wants a Wordpress site that allows its users to register for an annual golf tournament that they are hosting.  With registration comes two functions.

First, the actual registration process.
Second, through a separate form, the ability to create a foursome using the already registered users.

Does anyone know of a Wordpress plugin(s) that comes close to performing these functions?
Or am I going to have to write this one from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I could personally find was the [Event Registration Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/event-registration/), but I doubt it will do exactly what you need.

What you're looking for doesn't sound terribly complex, however, so I would just build it from the ground up.